# switch case em bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Meu `switch case` não está funcionando corretamente:

```
while getopts "hvo:umsf" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        i) instalarSniper
        ;;
        h) help
        ;;
        s) simular
        ;;
        d) adicionais
        ;;
        ?) echo "Parametros incorretos, digite -h para ajuda"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Mais especificamente, meus parâmetros `-h` e `-s` estão funcionando, mas se tento o `-i` ou `-d`, ele vai para o caso de parâmetros incorretos.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que está errado?

Answer (score 1):

No `getopts` você deve passar as opções que são aceitas. Como não tem a letra `i`, ela não vai ser reconhecida. Colocando somente as opções que estão no `case`, fica assim:

```
while getopts "hisd" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        i) instalarSniper
        ;;
        h) help
        ;;
        s) simular
        ;;
        d) adicionais
        ;;
        ?) echo "Parametros incorretos, digite -h para ajuda"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Assim, os parâmetros aceitos são `-h`, `-i`, `-s` e `-d`.

Se quiser opções mais complexas, veja o [tutorial de `getopts`](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

A resposta de @hkotsubo está óptima, junto apenas mais a estrutura típica de um script
bash com opções e parâmetros, de acordo com os meus gostos pessoais:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "hi:" OPT        ## processar opções
do
    case $OPT in
        i) iv=$OPTARG ; echo instalar $iv;;
        h) echo help           ; exit 0 ;;
       \?) echo "usage: $0 ..."; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))            ## avançar até argumentos

for a in "$@"                  ## processar argumento
do
  echo "=== processar '$a'==="
done
```